# SweetAlert printing error messages from array

Tags: sweetalert2

Can SweetAlert print error messages that are given to it from PHP via an array? If so, is there an example of this?

Specifically, can it read directly from a json_decode the actual error message to print?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please paste some codes. Thanks

Comment: @TheOracle I have not done anything because I am not even sure how to start.

Comment: Do you know how http/json-based api works? Do you know how to consume api data with javascript at the front-end? I think you should start from here.